# How can I dynamically change the table height according to the text in kivymd dataTable?

Tags: python, user-interface, kivy, kivymd

I'm creating a data table using kivyMD which has long texts in some columns.
The problem is the bad visualization of the long text which I cannot fix.
The example code for it is:
'

```
from kivy.metrics import dp
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.datatables import MDDataTable


class DynamicTableExample(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        layout = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')

        # Create a data table with custom cell height
        table = MDDataTable(
            #background_color_header="#65275d",
            #background_color_cell="#451938",
            #background_color_selected_cell="#451938",
            size_hint=(1, 1),
            use_pagination=True,
            check=True,
            column_data=[
                ("Header 1", dp(50)),  # Adjust the width as needed
                ("Header 2", dp(50)),
                ("Header 3", dp(50)),
            ],
            row_data=[
                ("This is a long text for Row 1 Data 1.\n " * 5, "This is a long text for without next line This is a long text for without next line This is a long text for without next line This is a long text for without next line ", "This is a long text for Row 1 Data 3"),
                ("51", "28", "387"),
                ("58", "42", "78"),
            ]
        )

        layout.add_widget(table)

        return layout

if __name__ == "__main__":
    DynamicTableExample().run()
```

I want the row's height to increase as the volume of the text increases.

Comment: All of these widgets inherit from main Widget class so they should have width, height properties, try them and see if you get what you looking for

Comment: It does accept width and height as a property, however, they are not relevant to the table . The width is defined in the column_data and the height remains as a question mark.